# mdadm RAID1 won't rebuild

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, mdadm, raid1

A drive on one of my Hetzner servers failed yesterday.
I've replaced it once before, but this time it just will not work.

After I copy the GPT to the new disk, I add one of the partitions to the array, like so:

mdadm /dev/md2 -a /dev/sda3

But then all I get is "spare rebuilding"

```
/dev/md2:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Mon Aug  6 12:26:06 2012
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 1073740664 (1024.00 GiB 1099.51 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1073740664 (1024.00 GiB 1099.51 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Fri Nov 27 21:20:22 2015
          State : clean, degraded, recovering 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

 Rebuild Status : 0% complete

           Name : rescue:2  (local to host rescue)
           UUID : 22dec46b:5085ad15:c6afdce0:7f025da4
         Events : 17901232

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       2       8       19        0      active sync   /dev/sdb3
       3       8        3        1      spare rebuilding   /dev/sda3
```

The rebuild just stops after +/- 25% (Which I believe was how full the partition was, but I don't know if that's how it should behave)

And the disk just stays a "spare", and I have no idea how to activate it.

So does anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

If the recovery starts but then stops abruptly at 25%, chances are that the other RAID1 disk member has some serious problem reading from its sectors. Anyway, I strongly suggest you to visit the [Linux MDRAID mailing list](http://marc.info/?l=linux-raid&r=1&w=2) to directly ask about your problem.